# how to get state of a Kafka broker using java?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I used kafka 9.0 and 'kafka_2.11:0.9.0.1' from maven to get the task done.
using ZkClient Classes i can get into Zookeeper being connected or not.
Then can also get Brokers List using ZkClient.getChildren('') method.

My scenario fails when i shutdown my Broker and try to call above scenario in that case Broker is going into Shutting Down state and code shows that Broker is attached. But i wanted to get its Status here .

i.e. Running/ ShuttingDown / Shutdown kind of states.

How can i get that using java code and kafka 9.0 apis.